# why is there a syntax error in connection PDO?

Tags: php, pdo

**config.ini**

```
[database]
host = 127.0.0.1
dbname = login
user = root
password =
```

**PHP**

```
$con = parse_ini_file('config.ini.php');
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');

try {
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$con['host'];dbname=$con['dbname']",$con['user'],$con['password']) ;
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOExpection $e ) {
die($e->getMessage());
}
```

when i try to connection this give me **syntax error** like this

> syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting
>   identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number
>   (T_NUM_STRING)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using interpolation to include array expression in your PDO `DSN` parameter. For that reason you've to use `{}` curly brackets inside your string

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host={$con['host']};dbname={$con['dbname']}", $con['user'], $con['password']) ;
```

Or just simply use concatenation.

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $con['host'] . ";dbname=" . $con['dbname'], $con['user'], $con['password']) ;
```